# Hibernate + Informix + Blob + byte array

Tags: java, hibernate, arrays, blob, informix

I have troubles saving a byte array to my Informix database, I'll show you how I'm trying:

In Fichero.java among other things I have this:

```
@Column(name="fichero", columnDefinition="blob")
private byte[] contenido;
```

I had to do that way because I can't get Informix+Hibernate to accept @Lob annotation (yes, I tried that extending Hibernate's dialect workaround but it doesn't work for me)

Then I read a file and convert it to a bytearray this way:
FileManager.java

```
private byte[] fromFile2ByteArray(String nombreFichero) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException{
   File file = new File(nombreFichero);
   InputStream is = new FileInputStream(file);
   byte[] contenido = new byte[(int)file.length()];
   is.read(contenido);
   is.close();
   return contenido;
}
```

And next I try to save it to my database using:
FicheroDAO.java

```
public void save(Object object) {
   getHibernateTemplate().save(object);      
}
```

where the object is my Fichero object.

Buuuuut, I get the following exception.

```
Hibernate: 
    /* insert es.cosas.modelo.datos.dominio.fichero.Fichero
        */ insert 
        into
            cosas_fichero
            (fichero, idEnvio, nombrefichero, respuesta) 
        values
            (?, ?, ?, ?)
WARN : org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter - SQL Error: -841, SQLState: S0000
ERROR: org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter - Name must start with a letter or '_' and contain letters, digits, or '_'.
22-jun-2012 9:25:32 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
GRAVE: Servlet.service() para servlet Spring MVC Dispatcher Servlet lanzó excepción
java.sql.SQLException: Name must start with a letter or '_' and contain letters, digits, or '_'.
   at com.informix.util.IfxErrMsg.getSQLException(IfxErrMsg.java:379)
   at com.informix.jdbc.IfxSqli.addException(IfxSqli.java:3109)
   at com.informix.jdbc.IfxSqli.receiveError(IfxSqli.java:3419)
   at com.informix.jdbc.IfxSqli.dispatchMsg(IfxSqli.java:2282)
   at com.informix.jdbc.IfxSqli.receiveMessage(IfxSqli.java:2202)
   at com.informix.jdbc.IfxSqli.executeFastPath(IfxSqli.java:5475)
   at com.informix.jdbc.IfxSqli.executeFastPath(IfxSqli.java:5400)
   at com.informix.jdbc.IfxSmartBlob.IfxLoColInfo(IfxSmartBlob.java:306)
   at com.informix.jdbc.IfxSmBlob.createSmartLob(IfxSmBlob.java:751)
   at com.informix.jdbc.IfxSmBlob.createBlobOnServer(IfxSmBlob.java:497)
   at com.informix.jdbc.IfxResultSet.executeUpdate(IfxResultSet.java:301)
   at com.informix.jdbc.IfxStatement.executeUpdateImpl(IfxStatement.java:885)
   at com.informix.jdbc.IfxPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(IfxPreparedStatement.java:279)
   at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:105)
   at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:105)
   at org.hibernate.id.insert.AbstractSelectingDelegate.performInsert(AbstractSelectingDelegate.java:57)
   at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2329)
   at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2836)
   at org.hibernate.action.EntityIdentityInsertAction.execute(EntityIdentityInsertAction.java:71)
   at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:267)
   at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:321)
   at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:204)
   at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:130)
   at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:210)
   at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:56)
   at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:195)
   at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:50)
   at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:93)
   at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.fireSave(SessionImpl.java:705)
   at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:693)
   at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:689)
   at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate$12.doInHibernate(HibernateTemplate.java:686)
   at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate$12.doInHibernate(HibernateTemplate.java:1)
   at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.doExecute(HibernateTemplate.java:406)
   at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.executeWithNativeSession(HibernateTemplate.java:374)
   at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.save(HibernateTemplate.java:683)
```

The next line in the exception points to FicheroDAO.java file and the line number where it tries to save the object...

Any ideas?

Comment: Well I tried again and it does accept @Lob but I get the same exact exception when saving...

Comment: As a side note: If I delete the byte[] fichero property and its corresponding column in the DB there's no problem saving, so it has to be something with the conversion from byte[] to blob or the way Hibernate builds the query...

Comment: Well in the end I figured out a more simple workaround: I just defined the column in the DB as byte... and it works like a charm...

Thanx anyway..

Comment: Are you familiar with how Informix stores and represents byte and blob datatypes?.. I don't think you can cast byte to a blob anyway. ¿Que tipo de data estas utilizando para almacenarlo en una columna tipo byte?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well in the end I figured out a more simple workaround: I just defined the column in the DB as byte... and it works like a charm... Thanx anyway..