# Informix: Can't persist entity using CLOB while VARCHAR works

Tags: hibernate, jakarta-ee, informix, sqldatatypes, clob

I got an entity with a column of type String. The underlying datatype is VARCHAR(255). If I change this datatype to CLOB, i get the following exception during

```
entityManager.persist(entity);
```

And here is the stacktrace

```
15:31:43,253 INFO  [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.AbstractBatchImpl] (EJB default - 4) HHH000010: On release of batch it still contained JDBC statements
15:31:43,268 WARN  [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] (EJB default - 4) SQL Error: -841, SQLState: S0000
15:31:43,268 ERROR [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] (EJB default - 4) Name must start with a letter or '_' and contain letters, digits, or '_'.
15:31:43,268 ERROR [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.BatchingBatch] (EJB default - 4) HHH000315: Exception executing batch [could not execute batch]
15:31:43,268 WARN  [com.arjuna.ats.arjuna] (EJB default - 4) ARJUNA012125: TwoPhaseCoordinator.beforeCompletion - failed for SynchronizationImple< 0:ffff968521df:1920e98e:5641ceff:adc0, org.hibernate.engine.transaction.synchronization.internal.RegisteredSynchronization@ac5829a >: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute batch
...
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute batch
at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:123)
at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:49)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:124)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.BatchingBatch.performExecution(BatchingBatch.java:122)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.BatchingBatch.doExecuteBatch(BatchingBatch.java:101)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.AbstractBatchImpl.execute(AbstractBatchImpl.java:161)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcCoordinatorImpl.executeBatch(JdbcCoordinatorImpl.java:207)
at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:390)
at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:303)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:349)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:56)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1195)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:404)
at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.synchronization.internal.SynchronizationCallbackCoordinatorNonTrackingImpl.beforeCompletion(SynchronizationCallbackCoordinatorNonTrackingImpl.java:109)
... 167 more
Caused by: java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Name must start with a letter or '_' and contain letters, digits, or '_'.
at com.informix.jdbc.IfxPreparedStatement.executeBatch(IfxPreparedStatement.java:3028)
at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrappedStatement.executeBatch(WrappedStatement.java:1077)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.BatchingBatch.performExecution(BatchingBatch.java:113)
... 177 more
```

I have no idea why the datatype has an impact on the persist-phase. Do you have any hint on what is going on here? If you need any code, please let me know. There is too much code that I could possibly provide.

Here is the entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "cw_test")
public class CwTest implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @Column(name="ID")
    private Integer id;
//  @Column(name = "TEST_COLUMN", columnDefinition="BLOB")
    @Column(name = "TEST_COLUMN")
    private String testColumn;

    public CwTest() {
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public void setTestColumn(String testColumn) {
        this.testColumn = testColumn;
    }

    public String getTestColumn() {
        return testColumn;
    }

}
```

And here is the sql-code

```
drop table CW_TEST;
create table CW_TEST(ID integer, TEST_COLUMN varchar(255));

drop table CW_TEST;
create table CW_TEST(ID integer, TEST_COLUMN CLOB);
```

The first works, while the second doesn't.

Here's the output with debug-option=true.

```
11:28:28,797 INFO  [stdout] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1) Hibernate: 
11:28:28,797 INFO  [stdout] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1)     /* insert de.lbank.frep.model.CwTest
11:28:28,797 INFO  [stdout] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1)         */ insert 
11:28:28,797 INFO  [stdout] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1)         into
11:28:28,797 INFO  [stdout] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1)             cw_test
11:28:28,797 INFO  [stdout] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1)             (TEST_COLUMN, ID) 
11:28:28,797 INFO  [stdout] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1)         values
11:28:28,797 INFO  [stdout] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1)             (?, ?)

11:28:28,829 INFO  [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.AbstractBatchImpl] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1) HHH000010: On release of batch it still contained JDBC statements
11:28:28,829 WARN  [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1) SQL Error: -841, SQLState: S0000
11:28:28,829 ERROR [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1) Name must start with a letter or '_' and contain letters, digits, or '_'.
11:28:28,829 ERROR [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.BatchingBatch] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1) HHH000315: Exception executing batch [could not execute batch]
11:28:28,829 WARN  [com.arjuna.ats.arjuna] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1) ARJUNA012125: TwoPhaseCoordinator.beforeCompletion - failed for SynchronizationImple< 0:ffff968521df:496f4a99:565d75bf:55, org.hibernate.engine.transaction.synchronization.internal.RegisteredSynchronization@2c18af11 >: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute batch
```

Here is my persistence.xml:

```
<persistence-unit name="persistence_unit" transaction-type="JTA">
    <jta-data-source>java:jboss/datasources/INF_APPDS</jta-data-source>

    <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.InformixDialect" />

        <property name="hibernate.jdbc.use_streams_for_binary" value="true" />

        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="${STAGING.hibernate.show_sql:false}" />
        <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true" />
        <property name="hibernate.use_sql_comments" value="true" />
        <property name="hibernate.jdbc.fetch_size" value="20" />
        <property name="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size" value="20" />
        <property name="hibernate.jdbc.batch_versioned_data" value="false" />


        <property name="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache" value="false" />
        <property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache" value="false" />
        <property name="hibernate.cache.provider_class" value="org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider" />
        <property name="hibernate.order_updates" value="true" />
        <property name="hibernate.generate_statistics" value="true" />
        <property name="hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings" value="true" />
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

Comment: How did you change it to CLOB ? Can you share the code of the entity ?

Comment: I changed it to CLOB, dropping the whole table. I will edit my initial post.

Comment: Are you setting the `hibernate.dialect` to `org.hibernate.dialect.InformixDialect` ?

Comment: Yes, i will add my persistence.xml to my initial post.

Comment: Check if this is of any help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11153226/hibernate-informix-blob-byte-array

Comment: Yes, I already saw this. Sadly, this is just a workaround...

Comment: The whole point of using CLOB is so that you can use partial reads and writes, so that the entire object does not have to be loaded into memory.  In order for Hibernate to be able to do that, Hibernate must have knowledge of the fact that this is a CLOB column.  But `columnDefinition="BLOB")` (BTW, I thought it should be "CLOB") just gives Hibernate a definition in text, it does not really let Hibernate know that this column is CLOB.  It appears that you are using JPA. Have you tried `@Lob(type = LobType.CLOB)`?

Answer (score 0):

if sql grammar exception is coming any where you have to check your POJO is mapped with whatever table you create in your DB. Or you can use

```
<property name="hbm2ddl.auto" value="create"/>
```

Comment: As you can see, my pojo is mapped to the table...Furthermore, the property does't change a thing. I am still getting the same exception.

Comment: But here  you are working with only two  datatype. CLOB we are using for handling a large amount of data..

Comment: It doesn't matter with how many datatypes we are working...Even with one field you can have massive data to be stored in it.

Comment: By the way: I am not using any hibernate mapping files. If this was your assumption.

Comment: CwTest this pojo your using Right.

Comment: You are using annotation based var so no need  to write separate XML file

Comment: Ankit: Yes, CwTest is the pojo which represents the table CW_TEST. You mean the persistence.xml? Where else will I make my definitions (like the definition of the InformixDialect) then?

Comment: Chris311: Inside persistence.xml you did not declare your class.

Comment: you can use like this.<class>package name.CwTest</class>

Comment: I tried this, but I still get the same exception. What should this be good for anyway?

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like you are using the default informix hibernate dialect in your mapping file. According to this post (http://www.snailshell.de/blog/archives/2007/06/entry_108.html) and the linked JIRA ticket (https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-2646), the default informix hibernate dialect doesn't support CLOB or BLOB types.

Have you verified that the dialect you are using supports this? Have you tried the custom dialect linked here?